# Ignore commas in fields in TSV file

Tags: beamer, pgfplotstable

I'm importing data from a tab-separated values file. Unfortunately, there's a comma in one of the fields: between the surname and firstname.

How can I ignore the comma when the file is imported so I can get the surname and name into the correct field: name.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{table.csv}
Subject Computer    Interested  Name    Profit  Signature
1   WORKSTATION001  no  Doe, John   0.00    
2   WORKSTATION002  OK  Doe, Jane   0.00    
Experiment          E:\Tomas\PhD\Econ Experiments\ztree-3_4_7 (1)\150209_1300.pay   0.00    
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[comment chars={E}]{table.csv}\mytable

\begin{frame}
      \pgfplotstabletypesetfile[
string type,
col sep=tab,
columns={Name,Profit},
ignore chars={,},format=file
] {\mytable}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a tab after the comma?

Comment: No tab directly after the comma, just a single space.

Comment: Look at your warnings probably filecontents is complaining about tabs being replaced with spaces. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: It's still not working. If you put the option `columns={Name,Profit},` into the `pgfplotstabletypesetfile` command, you'll see that the first name is going into the `profit` column.

Comment: Again, you are not reading the table properly. So it is picking up whatever it seems to have. They are not aligned properly hence they are not shifted to the next column. It's a filecontents problem. Also two consecutive tab characters are read as one so it can never match the header row with the data if you don't have something like `{}` in the empty cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the column separator when you read the table, not when you typeset it. Note that `pgfplotstable` was thus breaking on the space between `Doe,` and `John/Jane`, not on the comma. In addition, make sure that your columns are separated by tabs, the `filecontents` environment was writing spaces for me for some reason.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

% \begin{filecontents*}{table.csv}
% Subject   Computer    Interested  Name    Profit  Signature
% 1 WORKSTATION001  no  Doe, John   0.00
% 2 WORKSTATION002  OK  Doe, Jane   0.00
% \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[comment chars={E}, col sep=tab]{table.csv}\mytable

\begin{frame}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
string type,
columns={Name,Profit},
] {\mytable}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange, this doesn't work on my computer. Might be a 1.12 addition/fix.

Comment: @percusse Do you get an error or something? It took me a while to figure out that `filecontents` was writing spaces instead of tabs, and I was getting a `couldn't find that column` error...

Comment: Yes see my comments under the question. But probably I screwed the file while entering manually :)

Comment: @percusse Yes, I only saw those comments after I put my answer :)